# File could only be written to 0 of the 1 minReplication nodes

Tags: java, hadoop

server A: 192.168.96.130, OS: centos7.x
server B: Localhost,my computer, OS: windows10

I install Hadoop3.1.2 on serverA, and write Java Application to write data into HDFS on server A. 
When the Java Applicataion is deployed on server A, it can write files with content onto HDFS successfully.
When the Java Applicataion is deployed on server B, It can write files onto HDFS, But can't write the content in the file.  Always get the error:

```
2020-03-18 20:56:43,460 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 9 on 9000, call Call#4 Retry#0 org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.ClientProtocol.addBlock from 192.168.96.1:53463
java.io.IOException: File /canal/canal_1/canal_1-2020-3-19-4.txt could only be written to 0 of the 1 minReplication nodes. There are 1 datanode(s) running and 1 node(s) are excluded in this operation.
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager.chooseTarget4NewBlock(BlockManager.java:2121)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirWriteFileOp.chooseTargetForNewBlock(FSDirWriteFileOp.java:295)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:2702)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.addBlock(NameNodeRpcServer.java:875)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:561)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:523)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:991)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:872)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:818)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1729)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2678)
```

And below is my Java Application code:

```java
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
FileSystem fs= FileSystem.get(new URI("hdfs://192.168.96.1:9000/"),conf,"root");
FSDataOutputStream out = fs.create(new Path("/canal/canal_1/canal_1-2020-03-10.txt"));
out.writeBytes("15, kevin15, 2020.3.15");
out.flush();
out.close();
fs.close();
```

How to solve this probem?

Comment: use this command to check whether datanode is full or not. `$ dfs -du -h /`. or check datanode is **down**.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check your cluster healthy at first.`http://namenode1:50070`
then maybe you have not close your iptables ,so you cannot telnet the port when you on server2. you can try to execute command `telnet SERVER1_IP 50020` on server1 and server2  to check it .